# Extend wifi connection range

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

how to extend the range of a WiFi connection?. without using a repeater.

currently using 802.11b+g+n wireless type.

My Router model = Aztech Dsl5001en

When i go outside the house, the WiFi can't reach within 5-10 meters.

help please.

Comment: The repeater is the standard way. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: i know there is something wrong in my router, there must be something need to configure? i don't know how. -_- .

Answer (score 1):

You can try several things:

- If you don't have any 802.11b devices using the wifi, deactivate that mode. If no 802.11g devices are using the wifi, deactivate that mode also. If you can, force all devices to use 802.11n.
- Like x0a said, reduce the number of objects between your router and your clients. If possible, position your wireless router higher in the room (best would be halfway between the ceiling and the floor but that's not always doable, obviously).
- If your router is near a microwave, get it further away from the microwave or anything else producing 2.4 GHz radiation.
- The antenna your router came with can be seen as a very narrow cylinder. The signal is radiated from the sides of the cylinder, not from the tip. In other words, you'll get the **worst** signal quality ever if you point your cylinder like a magic wand towards the device you want to transmit to. Thus, if you have your antenna and your laptop on the same floor, always point your antenna towards the ceiling. Basically: experiment with different antenna angles and see what works best.
- Your router model suggests the antenna is detachable: you can try purchasing an omnidiretional antenna that gives you greater gain. Note however that an omni antenna with greater gain will increase the signal quality horizontally in exchange for a tighter angle (e.g. you get better signal horizontally but you get worse signal at 45 degrees that with a lower gain antenna, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Concrete, metal, chicken wire, and stone block WiFi signals, The less of these materials obstructing your signal, the better. So move accordingly. You can use a Pluglink or other ethernet adapter to help you make changes for a better connection as well.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Inssider and look for other Wi-Fi networks that are crossed with yours, try to change channel if something.
Update drivers on your Wi-Fi device.
P.S. Also the best position for Antenna is Vertical, if Wi-Fi device and Wi-Fi router on the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try is changing the bandwidth of your signal. The description page of your router ([[Aztech]](http://www.aztech.com/prod_adsl_dsl5001en.html/)) suggests you can use 20 and 40 MHz bandwidth. You may notice some improvement, but don't expect the range to double.